# saving output of pandas groupby.apply to new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, apply

I have a function that I'm trying to apply to a Pandas Dataframe in order to save the output of this function as a new column. I want to take a column of the grouped Dataframe which contains the indices of the rows per group. Based on these indices, function determines whether the row falls in the start, middle, or end of the group. I then want to save this output in a new column for that row.

This is the function:

```
def add_position_within_group(self,group):
    length_of_group = group.max()
    three_lists = self.split_lists_into_three_parts(range(length_of_group))
    for x in group:
        if int(x) in three_lists[0]:
            return 0
        elif int(x) in three_lists[1]:
            return 1
        elif int(x) in three_lists[2]:
            return 2
```

This is how I'm trying to apply it :

```
compound_data_frame["position_in_sequence"] = compound_data_frame.groupby('id')["group_index"].apply(self.add_position_within_group)
```

The new column has all NaN values when it should have either a 0, a 1, or a 2.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use `transform` instead of `apply`.

Comment: @Quang Hoang can you elaborate on why that's the case?

Comment: in sort, `apply` returns a number for each group, `transform` returns a series of the same length for each group. Since the number of groups are generally different from the number of rows, you cannot assign the `apply` output to the original dataframe.

Comment: Also, you need to review your `add_position_within_group` function. It does not run through the whole group.

Comment: @Quang Hoang how doesn't it run through the whole group? It iterates over the group with for "x in group:"

Comment: No, because you `return` something after every `if/else` statement.

Comment: @Quang Hoang if I use transform, doesn't the thing that I return get assigned to the column position_in_sequence for that row?

Comment: I tried returning a list but I got this error:  shape mismatch: value array of shape (79201,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (79202,)